# python equivalent for `eigs` in matlab with a matrix function

Tags: python, matlab

If I want to calculate the k smallest eigenvalues of the matrix multiplication AA' with A of size 300K by 512 and "'" is the transpose, then that would be infeasible to do it in traditional way. Matlab however provides a nice functionality by using a function argument that perform the product `Afun = @(x) A*(A'*x));` to the `eigs` function. Then, to find the smallest 6 eigenvalues/eigenvectors we call `d = eigs(Afun,300000,6,'smallestabs')`, where the second input is the size of the matrix AA'. Is there a function in python that performs a similar thing?

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, there is no such functionality in `numpy`. However, I don't see any limitations by using simply [`numpy.linalg.eigvals`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvals.html#numpy-linalg-eigvals) for retrieving an array of the matrix eigenvalues. Then simply find the N smallest with a sort:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg

A = np.array() # your matrix
eigvals = numpy.linalg.eigvals(A)
eigvals.sort()
smallest_6_eigvals = eigvals[:6]
```